# Set of all points the same distance from a line and a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Let $l$ be a line and let $\gamma$ be a circumference. If $\gamma \cap l = \emptyset$, what is the set of all points that are the same distance from $\gamma$ and $l$?

I draw a sketch and I think that it's a Parabola with $l$ being the directrix, but I can't find what the focus would be. Is this correct? If so, how Can I Prove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a parabola, with its focus at the center of circle $\gamma$, and its directrix parallel to $l$, at a distance from it equal to the radius of $\gamma$.

[image]

Comment: Why? I don't see why that would be the case, is there any intuition behind that?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães I added a picture.

Comment: Thanks @Intelligentipauca I understand now

Answer (score 2):

The focus will be the center of the circle. The distance from a point to a circle is the distance from that point to the center of the circle minus radius. Thus, by definition of parabola we have a a set of all points whose distance from a certain point (circle center) is equal to their distance from a certain line. The directrix will be line parallel to $l$.